# How to calculate a median and mean of 95 percentile in R

Tags: r, mean, median

My dataset contains multiple observations (Mean Intensity gfp) for different species (aapl2). Each species has a several number of observations.

I have already grouped observations in groups by species and calculated 95 percentil with:

> data2 = aggregate(data$"Mean Intensity gfp" ~ data$aapl2, FUN = quantile, probs = c(0.95)).

But now, I have problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I need to calculate a **median and mean of calculated 95 percentile** , but I really don't know how to do it.

Could somebody help me, please?

Thank you very very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDLu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using iris... To get the mean/median of those where the value is below the 95th percentile (of its species)

```
library(data.table)
data.table(iris)[, keep := Petal.Length < quantile(Petal.Length, 0.95), 
                   by = Species][
                   keep==TRUE, 
                   .(mean(Petal.Length), median(Petal.Length)), 
                   by = Species]
```

And using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(Petal.Length < quantile(Petal.Length, 0.95)) %>%
  summarize("mean"=mean(Petal.Length), 
            "med"=median(Petal.Length))
```

Comment: And can I, in some way, combine, a calculation of the median of 95 percentile?

Because the tapply function gives a table of 95 percentil, but not a median of 95 percentil for each species.

Comment: You mean you want the median of the individuals that fall within the middle 95%/the first/95%? Or you want a mean/median of the estimates of 95%iles

Comment: Yes exactly, I need the median and mean of the first 95% observations in each group.

Comment: Ok, see edit - if that answers it let me know and I'll edit the answer to clean it up

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is still not working. 
I have an error message:
Error in `[.data.table`(data.table(data), , `:=`(keep, data$`Mean Intensity gfp` <  : 
  Supplied 479236 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 220 in column 'keep'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: Try it with the built in iris data first, then edit that code so that iris becomes data, Species becomes aapl2, and Petal.Length becomes Mean Intensity gfp (you'll need to wrap that in back ticks if that actually has spaces in the variable name)

Comment: With iris data.table it works normally.

Comment: Ok, then carefully edit that code and try again

Comment: Finally, it looks promising. 
I have only error message:
Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Where is (1-h)*qs[i] cokming from now?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking for now?
Reply to: Where is (1-h)*qs[i] cokming from now?

Comment: Just added a dplyr version, see if that works instead. Regarding the last comment, what code is causing that error - (1-h)... isn't in any if the above

Comment: The last dplyr version, isn not working. 
The error message with (1-h)... was after using:
data.table(iris)[, keep := Petal.Length < quantile(Petal.Length, 0.95), 
                   by = Species][
                   keep==TRUE, 
                   .(mean(Petal.Length), median(Petal.Length)), 
                   by = Species]

Comment: Ok, you need to provide a reproducible example of your data because the problem lies there, not with the code I've written as that works on other data. See `dput()`

Comment: I edited the question and attached a picture of my data.

Comment: Please read the help pages on providing a reproducible example

Comment: Hi @BarboraOtáhalová, pictures of data are not useful (see [ask], but also [mre] is pertinent). As rg255 suggested, use `dput()` and copy its output to your question so that anyone can use it to have the exact same data as yours.